# show loading div with overlay on submit while waiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My divs are not showing when I click on submit.

I can get them to show if I do a `window.onload()` but the divs have to have `display: none;` by default;

How can I make it so these divs show when I hit submit because my form takes about 30 seconds to process, it has a lot of fields.

HTML

```
<div id="overlay-back"></div>
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="dvLoading">
        <p>Please wait<br>while we are loading...</p>
        <img id="loading-image" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
    </div>
</div>
```

Submit Button

```
  <div class="form-buttons-wrapper">
        <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="form-submit-button">
             Submit
        </button>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
position : absolute;
top      : 0;
left     : 0;
width    : 100%;
height   : 100%;
z-index  : 995;
display  : none;
} 
#overlay-back {
position   : absolute;
top        : 0;
left       : 0;
width      : 100%;
height     : 100%;
background : #000;
opacity    : 0.6;
filter     : alpha(opacity=60);
z-index    : 990;
display    : none;
}
#dvLoading {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 10px;
height: 150px;
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin: -125px 0 0 -125px;
text-align: center;
display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#submit').on('submit', function() {
        $('#dvLoading, #overlay, #overlay-back').prop("display", "block").fadeIn(500);
    });    
});    
</script>
```

The reason I am displaying none by default in css because if someone has javascript disabled I do not want any inteference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#dvLoading, #overlay, #overlay-back').fadeIn(500);
    });    
});    
</script>
```

The fadeIn will make the div visible.

```
.prop sets the properties of the element, not the style.
```

- Changed to use the click event

Comment: That did not work :S does it matter if I place this in the head element or at the bottom of my script? I assume it does not matter.

Comment: Because it is a form, it is best to wrap this functionality is a condition that will check if the form is valid also, before firing.  Then wrap it in an onclick function do this: $('#dvLoading, #overlay, #overlay-back').toggle(500);

Comment: It doesn't matter because of the $(function() wrapper.

Comment: so what I did was add the handling on the form.submit handler in my jQuery validate, so it will trigger the divs for me when the validation is true.

Comment: do not use submit button click event to handle form submit.  the form's submit event is what you need to use.  form could be submitted with enter key, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your own custom form validation as I have no context to supplement that.  This should be placed in a document ready OR in a setInterval JavaScript function (the latter typically yeilds much better results).

```
$('button#submit').click(function() {
If (formValid === true &&  $('#dvLoading, #overlay, #overlay-back').not(':visible');)
{
    $('#dvLoading, #overlay, #overlay-back').toggle(500);
    $('button#submit').toggle(500); //hide this to prevent multiple clicks and odd behavior
} else {
var doNothing = "";
}
});
```